# why does python ignore this parameter?

Tags: python, oop

I'm writing a very simple class and I'm running into the weirdest problem.

here's the first class:

```
class Product:
    discount_rate = 0.9 

    def __init__(self, name, cost, category, quantity, discount=False, profit_margin=0.1):


        self.name = name
        self.category = category
        self.discount = discount
        self.quantity = quantity

        if self.discount:
            self.actualCost = float(cost) * self.discount_rate
        if not self.discount:
            self.actualCost = float(cost)

        self.cost = self.actualCost + (self.actualCost * profit_margin)
```

I tried to test this class out by creating some dummy data in another class, however, I won't attach the entire other class since the dummy data is just a class variable in it and nothing else and this problem persists even without the data being in another class.

here's the dummy data:

```
    dummyData = [Product('name1', 100, 'misc', 4, True), Product('name2', 20, 'fruit', 2, False),
                 Product('name3', 10, 'misc', 1, False), Product('name4', 5, 'misc', 10, True),
                 Product('name5', 5, 'fruit', 3, True)]
```

now logically, if I were to access the "cost" attribute of the first element of this dummy data, I should get 110, similarly if I tried to access the "actualCost" parameter I should get 100 but the output I do get is this:

```
cost = 99.0, actualCost = 90.0
```

furthermore, changing the discount variable to be "True" as a default parameter doesn't change anything either.

If I'm not wrong then this output is correct if the discount parameter was set to True but it gives me the same value regardless of the value of the discount parameter. what's going wrong here?

Comment: The values you expect would only be correct if you passed `False` for the discount argument but you pass `True`

Comment: Why do you think you should get 110? `self.cost = self.actualCost + (self.actualCost * profit_margin)` is `self.cost = 90 + (90 * 0.1)` which is 99.

Comment: On an unrelated note: If you have `if condition: something; if not condition: something_else` then that's the same as `if condition: something; else something_else`

Comment:  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

The default value of `discount` does not matter since all your products explicitly set the `discount` flag in their invocation.

Looking at the first product it is discounted since you specify `True` as the 5th parameter, therefore `actualCost = 100 * 0.9 = 90`. The `cost` then becomes `90 + 90 * 0.1 = 99`.

The math is entirely correct, your assumptions of what the code *should* produce is simply wrong.

Comment: oh my god you're right I'm so dumb, sorry! I'm gonna delete this post if I can.